What is the difference between quantum field theory (QFT) and relativistic quantum theory?
I am confused that what is the difference between quantum field theory and relativistic quantum theory? And I know these two theories are certainly not the same thing since wave and particles are unified in the field when we are dealing QFT, but in relativistic quantum mechanics (RQM) wave and particle are unified in the wave-particle duality.
So, what I wanna know is that

Is my argument that QFT and RQM are different a right interpretation?

If QFT and RQM are actually not the same thing, then what is the difference? And how do we understand the difference from the first principles (I mean by giving axioms and definitions , then make your point)?

Why we seldom talk about wave functions in QFT? And I will be very grateful if there is any example about wave function in QFT.



First, note that not all quantum field theories are relativistic. Non-relativistic QFTs are very important in condensed matter physics, for example.
Second, interacting relativistic quantum mechanics does not exist. Meaning, there is no theory of a single, relativistic particle, that interacts with other particles. The physical reason is a combination of the uncertainty principle and the existence of anti-particles: once a particle becomes relativistic, it becomes possible to have processes where particle-anti-particle pairs are generated. Therefore, a relativistic quantum mechanical theory will necessarily be a theory with an arbitrary number of particles, not just one particle. This is discussed, for example, in Tong's QFT notes, or the first few lectures of Coleman's QFT course, or any QFT book.
Third, relativistic QFT "saves the day" because it naturally describes a theory of an indefinite number of identical particles. This is precisely the formalism that is needed to handle the issue described above. Weinberg's QFT book, especially chapters 2-5, give a very logical path starting from particles and arguing that on the basis of relativistic locality and causality, as well as quantum mechanical unitarity, we are led naturally to consider QFTs.
Finally, the main reason people don't talk about wave functionals in QFT is that they are hard to work with. Since the fundamental object in QFT is a field, the wave functional is a map from configurations of the field, to probability amplitudes. This is much more complicated than the wave function in single particle quantum mechanics, which maps the position of the particle to probability amplitudes. However, there are some nice results using the wavefunctional, and wikipedia has a nice introduction.

Your third point is essential: QFT is the only game in town if you want to deal with a variable number of particles.

It is interesting to stress, concerning your second point, that the problem is not confined to the quantum realm. No relativistic interacting (Hamiltonian) mechanics for a finite number of particles exists. That is consequence of the so called no-interaction theorem. Also classically one needs fields.

The difference is explained in Dyson's Advanced QM, in the last section of chapter 3.
In brief, relativistic QM is Dirac's theory of a single fermion, such as the electron. The many particle version of this theory, investigated by Dirac himself, becomes "hopelessly complicated" and is "nonsense" when particle number is not preserved.
He then goes on to say that this theory goes wrong in representing a particle by an operator dependent upon its position at time t. This "made the interpretation of the formalism essentially non-relativistic even when the equations were formally invariant". He then goes on to say:

Relativistic quantum theory [he means QFT] is the study of quantities $\phi$ which are functions of four coordinates $x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3$, all the coordinates being c-numbers [ordinary numbers and not operators] and only the expressions containing $\phi$ being operators describing the dynamical theory.


The dynamical system is specified by the quantity $\phi$ existing at all pounts of spacetime, and so consists of a system of fields. Relativistic quantum theory is neccessarily a field theory [that is a QFT].


After thinking for a long time, I think that I have an answer.
Firstly, there are only two kinds of field, classical field and quantum field. And quantum mechanics plus special relativity results only in quantum field, but not relativistic quantum mechanics, because relativistic quantum mechanics is ill-defined. By using the word ill-defined, I mean that the relativistic quantum mechanics has problems that can't be solved within its own theoretical framework. Two typical examples are Klein-Gordon equation
\begin{align}
(\partial^2-m^2)\psi(x)=0,
\end{align}
and Dirac equation
\begin{align}
(i \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\psi(x)=0.
\end{align}
In Klein-Gordon equation, there is a fatal problem which is negative probability, Dirac solved this problem with Dirac equation. But a new problem emerges in Dirac equation, which is negative energy. To explain negative energy, Dirac proposed a theory, the Dirac sea, but this bold guess didn't really solve the problem because if the Dirac sea theory is real, how do we explain the infinitely large gravitational effect produced by negative energy particles?
You can see now, in relativistic quantum mechanics, there are always problems. And in many quantum mechanics textbooks, these problems(negative energy and negative possibility) are avoided by introducing the second quantization. For example the Klein-Gordon equation after second quantization turns into:
\begin{align}
&(\partial^2-m^2)\phi(x)=0,\\
&\phi(x)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\left(\hat{a}_{p}e^{i p\cdot x}+a^{\dagger}_{p}e^{-i p\cdot x}\right),
\end{align}
$phi(x)$ is no longer wave function, but an operator, only when $\phi(x)$ acts on a quantum state $|\Psi\rangle$, particles can be produced. What about wave? The field operator $\phi(x)$ satisfy the wave equation, which is Klein-Gordon equation, thus it is $\phi(x)$ propagate from one point to another point. In conclusion, particles are excitations of quantum fields and waves are propagations of field operators. This is very different from the clumsy interpretation,  the particle-wave-duality in quantum mechanics, and thus I think quantum field is more fundamental theory.
Well it seems that we have gone too far off the topic, let's return to the second quantization. By introducing creation and annihilation operators $a^{\dagger}$ and $a$, which is basically second quantization method, the field emerges automatically. However, I think Weinberg's way of introducing quantum field is more natural than second quantization method(see Weinberg's book: Quantum Theory of Field, Vol-1, chapter 5), which claims that there is no second quantization, quantum mechanics plus special relativistic inevitably result in quantum field. I don't want to copy the book here since Weinberg has make his point clearly, anyone who is interested may read chapter 5 of Quantum Theory of Field, Vol-1.
Therefore, the conclusion is that relativistic quantum mechanics is an ill-defined terminology, and it is merely a product of history. When we mix the quantum mechanics and special relativity, what we actually obtain is quantum field.
By the way, the quantum field theory is not an ultimate theory, it still have many problems. And since I am just a beginner for quantum field theory, there must be something I still do not know or misunderstood, and I will be very grateful that if anyone could point it out.
